# Issues with copy constructor in custom Matrix class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, matrix, copy-constructor

I have a custom matrix class, that works fine in and of itself. The issue I'm running into is that when I try to create a new matrix defined by another matrix, the whole matrix isn't copied.

The matrix itself is basically just a pointer to a one dimensional array of doubles, where I have a custom function for finding the correct m x n index.
I've created a copy constructor as well as overloading the = operator. I think it's really strange that only parts of the matrix is copied over.

The issue may be with how I treat my pointers as I don't grasp it fully.

When I try to do this:

```
Matrix m(3,10);

for(int i = 0; i<m.getColumns(); i++){
   m.set(0,i, 4);
}

Matrix l(m);
Matrix c = m;

cout << m << endl;
cout << l << endl;
cout << c << endl;
```

I get this output:

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 


4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 


4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is my Matrix.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
private:
    int r;
    int c;
    int getIndex(int r, int c) const;
    double* matrix;
public:
    Matrix(int nRows, int nColumns);
    explicit Matrix(int nRows);
    Matrix(const Matrix &);
    ~Matrix();
    double get(int row, int col) const;
    void set(int row, int col, double value);
    int getRows() const;
    int getColumns() const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Matrix& m);
    Matrix& operator=(Matrix rhs);
};
```

This is the class' definition:

```
#include <Matrix.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix(int nRows, int mColumns)
{
    assert(nRows>0 && mColumns>0);

    r = nRows;
    c = mColumns;
    matrix = new double[r*c]{};

    //fills with zeros
    for(int i = 0; i<r*c; i++){
        matrix[i] = 0;
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(int nRows)
{  
    assert(nRows>0);

    r = nRows;
    c = nRows;
    matrix = new double[r*c]{};
    for(int i = 0; i<r*c; i++){
        matrix[i] = 0;
    }
    //Makes the identity matrix
    for(int i = 0; i<r; i++){
        set(i,i, 1);
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& other){
    r = other.getRows();
    c = other.getColumns();
    matrix = new double[r*c];
    *matrix = *other.matrix;
}



int Matrix::getIndex(int row, int col) const
{
    int index = row*c;
    index += col;
    return index;
}

int Matrix::getRows() const
{
    return r;
}
int Matrix::getColumns() const
{
    return c;
}

void Matrix::set(int row, int col, double value){
    matrix[getIndex(row, col)] = value;
}

double Matrix::get(int row, int col) const{
    return matrix[getIndex(row,col)];
} 

Matrix::~Matrix()
{

}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Matrix& m){
    for(int i = 0; i<m.getRows(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<m.getColumns(); j++){
            os << m.get(i,j);
            os << ' ';
        }
        os << '\n';
    }
    os << endl;
    return os;
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator=(Matrix rhs){
    r = rhs.r;
    c = rhs.c;
    swap(matrix, rhs.matrix);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: `*matrix = *other.matrix;` that is not how to copy a C-style array.  You will have a much easier time using `std::vector` instead of raw pointers and C style arrays.

Comment: Why is your destructor for `Matrix` commented out?  You've messed up `operator=` by doing this.  The bottom line is this -- if you have a class that has to manage a resource, and you need to provide a user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor, you have to be *all in* and write all of the functions required -- you can't stub out functions and have a program that can be tested.

Comment: the member `matrix` can be a `std::vector`. If you do not want to use `std::vector`, you should still write a class that only manages a 1d dynamic array, because thats more than enough for a class to do

Comment: `Matrix::~Matrix() { }` -- To be exact, your `operator=` requires that your `Matrix` destructor works properly and calls `delete[]` on the data.  Since you are using `swap` and you are passing `Matrix` by value in the assignment operator, everything working in the assignment operator is predicated on the copy constructor *and* destructor to be coded properly.  Otherwise you have a broken program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement in the copy constructor

```
*matrix = *other.matrix;
```

is equivalent to

```
matrix[0] = other.matrix[0];
```

That is it sets only one element of the newly created array but you need to copy all elements.

You could use for loop as for example

```
for ( int i = 0; i < r * c; i++ )
{
    matrix[i] = pther.matrix[i];
}
```

Or you could use standard algorithm `std::copy` declared in header `<algorithm>`

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::copy( other.matrix, other.matrix + r * c, matrix );
```

As you are using the fundamental type double then you can also use standard C function `memcpy` declared in header `<cstring>` like

```
#include <cstring>

//...

std::memcpy( matrix, other.matrix, r * c * sizeof( double ) );
```

Also the destructor shall free the allocated memory

```
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    delete [] matrix;
}
```

Otherwise the copy assignment operator defined like

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(Matrix rhs){
    r = rhs.r;
    c = rhs.c;
    swap(matrix, rhs.matrix);
    return *this;
}
```

will produce a memory leak.

And in this constructor

```
Matrix::Matrix(int nRows, int mColumns)
{
    assert(nRows>0 && mColumns>0);

    r = nRows;
    c = mColumns;
    matrix = new double[r*c]{};

    //fills with zeros
    for(int i = 0; i<r*c; i++){
        matrix[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

this for loop

```
    //fills with zeros
    for(int i = 0; i<r*c; i++){
        matrix[i] = 0;
    }
```

is redundant. The elements of the allocated array were already set to zeroes in this statement

```
    matrix = new double[r*c]{};
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not copy data from one array to the other:

`*matrix = *other.matrix;`

A loop is required to copy the data, `memcpy`, or use `std::copy`:

`std::copy(other.matrix, other.matrix + r*c, matrix);`